# Can REST-API controller packaged in JAR be called?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have packaged and deployed my TestRestController.java(PFB code) in a JAR(testrest.jar) in an EAR in JBOSS EAP-6.2,

How can I access my REST-API, i tried hitting the http://{WEB-SERVER-IP}:8080/testrest/test/execute URL from a REST client? But I get HTTP 404.

Is it even possible?

```
TestRestController.java:

@Path("/test")
public class TestRestController
{

    @POST
    @Path("/execute")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response executeRestApi(TestControllerDTO testControllerDto)
    {
        try
        {
            if (validateRequestParams(testControllerDto))
            {
                System.out.println("Validation success.");
                response = Response.status(Status.OK).entity("Validation success.").build();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Validation failed.");
                response = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("Validation failed.").build();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("Validation failed.").build();
        }
        return response;
    }

    private boolean validateRequestParams(TestControllerDTO testControllerDto)
    {
        boolean areParamsValid = false;
        if (null != testControllerDto)
        {
            areParamsValid = true;
        }
        return areParamsValid;
    }
}
```

Please help me.

P.S. : I am a newbie to Java and REST.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note your resource class is "mounted" on the path /test/execute and not /testrest/test/execute (as you tried)

Comment: @ShmilTheCat
My jar name is testrest.jar hence I tried the path /testrest/test/execute.
But, as u said, I also tried the /test/execute, even that throws HTTP 404.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initiate the rest servlet somehow. The easiest way is to just add an [`javax.ws.rs.core.Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) with an [`@ApplicationPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) annotation to your application.

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRSApplication extends Application {

}
```

It can be left empty. It can packaged either in your .jar or in the .war (keep in mind, the .jar should also be included in the war in the WEB-INF/lib).  With this the rest servlet will get initialized automatically and the classpath will be scanned for your resource classes annotated with `@Path`

You can see other deployment options [**here**](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.5.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html) and for more detailed information, you can see [**the spec**](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec.html).

With the above Application class, you should be able to access

> `http://localhost:8080/my-app/rest/test/execute`

Comment: Hi @peeskillet,

I added your code so that JBOSS will scan @Path attribute(as mentioned by you).
PFB the structure of my deployment in JBOSS:

 mytest.ear
 |
 |---mytestjar.jar
 | |--- TestRestController.class
 | |--- JaxRSApplication.class
 | |--- Other classes....
 | 
 ` 
 
I hit the following URL: `http://localhost:8080/mytest/rest/test/execute` and `http://localhost:8080/mytest/mytestjar/rest/test/execute` but I still get the HTTP 404.

Please tell what is wrong, URL or anything else.

Comment: The rest application needs to be packaged in a .war if it is to be deployed to JBOSS

Comment: No, all those classes _can_ be in a .jar, but that jar needs to be deployed with a .war. You could create an empty webapp and just add the .jar to the project as a depedencies

Comment: If possible, can you share any official document stating this point?

Comment: Notice the part _"The application classes are packaged in WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib"_. If your jar is added as a dependency correctly to your webapp, it should end up in the WEB-INF/lib. Just tested with EAP and works fine.

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet.
Was able to call REST-API successfully by packaging my classes in a WAR.